# exception handling for servicemodel exceptions

Tags: c#, exception

I have a wpf application, which consumes wcf service. I wish to catch any exceptions during the service request.
So I have something like this

```
 try{  call to service }
  catch(CommunicationObjectFaultedException){}
   catch (EndpointNotFoundException){}
```

Instead of doing the above for each and every request, How can I create a single function to handle the exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lambda will get that done, like this:

```
    public static bool TryExecute(Action a) {
        try {
            a();
            return true;
        }
        catch (CommunicationObjectFaultedException) { }
        catch (EndpointNotFoundException) { }
        return false;
    }
```

And use like this:

```
        bool ok = TryExecute(() => {
            // call to service
            //...
        });
```